# PHP Performance: Avoid often method calling

Tags: php, performance, class

i have a question about PHP performance.
I'm using my class methods very often in one instance. For example i have method for calculation a starting time of production shift. Calculation can be used just once, because for all calculations is the same start time.

Analysis tool: **xdebug** (this function is called mostly and takes longest time)

What is best way how to perform script? I dont wanna make a lot of static (about 20) variables.. Or best way is using static functions for this case?

Now for very often called functions im using:

```
class test{
   private $data;

        public function __construct () {
         $this->data=0;
        }

        public function foo() {
          if($this->data === 0) {
          // some code

           $this->data=$result;
          }
        return $this->data;
        }
}
```

I think this isnt good way how to solve my problem.
Thanks you for your time.

Comment: "I think this isnt good way"....because? What's your specific concern?

Comment: I didn't get the question itself :(

Answer (score 2):

Using setter functions for setting object properties is the right way to go. Only difference I would make is removing the return from foo() function and just accessing the property directly when needed.

```
 public function foo() {

    // some code

     $this->data=$result;
  }
```

Now after calling foo() once, you can use the **$this->data** to access the result every time without calling the function again and doing unnecessary calculations.